# Accessing service call through local ip address

Tags: angular, http, service, webserver, production-environment

Accessing service through local ip address `http://127:0.0.1:8080/GetDateRange` from Angular `http.get` call doesn't work. Running `curl 127.0.0.1:8080/GetDateRange` on the local machine does work. Accessing service call through local IpV4 ip address works as well.

Cors: Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to '*', default header settings.

Having this issue with both BaseHTTPServer (Python) and Apache. I am targeting production environment.

Where to look for the solution to the problem? Maybe in the direction of the `hosts` file?

Running Debian Jessie distro on a Raspberry Pi.

-- Edit
Tested the bare essence, and after some Googling I think this is some of a server setting.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

  console.log('this.readyState', this.readyState);

  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
  }
};
// this fails > 404
xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/GetDateRange", true);
// this works
// http.open("GET", "http://10.1.0.39:8080/GetDateRange", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Comment: I'm targeting production environment, this seems to be a solution for dev env.

Comment: Try  ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 and see if it works.

Comment: well, this still is for a dev environment, hence: ng serve >> localhost:4200

Comment: I need the client app to run on a different prod environments (multiple, standalone Raspberry Pi's, targeting a backend on 127.0.0.1:8080 (so I don't have to hardcode the local IP address for every individual situation)